# VBA: DataValidation

Tags: excel, vba

I record macro but when I start it, I receive error message

```vb
Sub Macro1()

    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:= _
        "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(""System_General_Cargo[[#Headers];[Location]]"");MATCH(B12;INDIRECT(""System_General_Cargo[Location]"");0);1;COUNTIF(INDIRECT(""System_General_Cargo[Location]"");B12);1)"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

This is macro from macro recorder. When I start it error occures Run Time error 1004

Comment: We need more information. What is the expected result of this macro? When does it trigger?

Comment: Try swapping out `;` for `,` in your formula.  VBA doesn't use the local settings..... or maybe try 'Formula2Local`.

Comment: Might be something with your `Formula1` argument.  Can you try putting that formula in your Excel sheet somewhere, and then referencing the range it's on instead?  Also, try using some other simple case, like `Formula1:="=$E$1:$E$5"` just to see if that works.  If that does work, you almost certainly know the issue is with the `Formula1`.